# Is there a way to make this recursive function faster?

Tags: c#, math

I am trying to get numbers that sum up 28.(this is just an example, however the target number can be changed). The below piece of code take approximately 4-5 min. Is there a way to make it a little faster to get combinations of numbers that sum up to "28"
**output example** 0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3

```
    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int up = 28;
        int rows = 12;

        int[] chosen = new int[rows + 1];
        CalculateCombination(chosen, 0, rows, 0, up - 1);
    }

    public void CalculateCombination(int[] chosen, int index, int r, int start, int end)
    {
        if (index == r)
        {
            return;
        }
        for (int i = start; i <= end; i++)
        {
            chosen[index] = i;
            CalculateCombination(chosen, index + 1, r, i, end);
            if (chosen.Sum() + chosen.Length == 28)
            {
                var ch = string.Join(",", chosen.Take(chosen.Length - 1));
                Debug.Write(ch);
                Debug.WriteLine("\t");
            }
        }
        return;
    }
```

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://thomaslevesque.com/2011/09/02/tail-recursion-in-c/) and see if it helps.

Comment: I am a little confused... You want to input a number and get _all_ combinations of numbers that add up to it?  Like `1+27, 2+26, 3+25, etc etc`?  Do you only want 2 number combinations or any number of combinations (i.e `1+1+1+1+1...`)?  What is the `Qty` array supposed to do?

Comment: I know this might sound stupid but the way you improve the performance of a recursive function the most is by trying to implement it non-recursively or at least with as little recursion as possible. All those function calls drastically slow it down as you have noticed. If it were possible to implement it completely non-recursive it would probably be immensely faster. Even though you might already know this I'll leave this as a comment because I didn't find any indications that you'd want to get rid of the recursion.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is more appropriately asked on codereview.SE.  We don't typically "help" with code that works.

Comment: What's with the `arr` argument that's never used?

Comment: maccettura, yes I was trying to get all possible combination 12 numbers that sum up 28 with the array length. like 
0,0,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do. And even so, the code seems not correct. I would forget about speed now and start with proper description of your goal.

Comment: @Zola that's a lot of combinations and it's going to take a very long time.

Comment: Goal is entirely unclear. Please provide a example of the input and output. Use something a bit smaler then 28 if you need to. I added the math tag in hope somebody there has an *idea* what you are even *trying* to do.

Comment: @ Antonín Lejsek - I took out the array if that confuse everyone

Comment: @Joelius Doing this non-recursively will not speed it up if the loops are still doing a brute force method. Recursive Fibonacci without memoization is really slow because of this but recursive Quick-Sort and recursive Fast Fourier Transform are FAST because of recursion.

Comment: The code would be more readable if you used more descriptive variable names and didn't create and pass around objects that aren't used, like `upArr` (which is only created and then passed to `CalculateRepetition`, where it isn't used). For example, what does the number specified by `rows` represent? Why is it needed? Also, none of the methods return a value. Shouldn't `CalculateRepetition` return something that represents all the combinations of numbers that add up to the input number? The call might look like `List<List<int>> result = GetAllPossibleSumCombinations(int targetNumber);`

Comment: @Sam: _"this is more appropriately asked on codereview.SE"_ -- only if they can improve the question. As asked, it would be off-topic there as well, because the code example is not complete. I have the impression that the codereview users are a bit tired of us stackoverflow users sending these kinds of poor questions to them. On _any_ Stack Exchange site, it's important for users to read the tour and help sections before posting their first question. Sadly, most do not, or fail to heed what they have read. :(

Comment: @ Rufus L - run the piece of code and see. What I want is to cut the execution time at list by half

Answer (score 3):

First off, I assume you are doing this for an assignment. **You are required to cite sources that helped you rather than passing off my work as your own** in an academic context, so make sure to document in your assignment where you got help from. Don't just copy a solution and claim it as your own.

---

UPDATE: I misunderstood the problem from the description; I understood the problem to be to find the **monotone nondecreasing** sequences of length 12 that sum to 28.  The problem has been clarified by the original poster in a comment; the problem is to find **all non-negative sequences** of a given length, say, 12 that sum to a given value, say, 28.  There are 1676056044 such sequences, and enumerating them all will take *some time*.  The answer which follows is addressed to the problem as I originally understood it.

---

Yes, this problem can be solved much more efficiently and clearly than you're doing here. Let's break it down.

First off, every recursive problem has one or more *base cases*. These are the cases that are so simple that they cannot be reduced to a simpler problem.  Let's make an entrypoint and then list the base cases.  What do we want? We want *all the sequences of a given length, in order from smallest to largest, such that the sequence sums to a particular value.*

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> SumsTo(int sum, int least, int length)
{
```

OK, what are the base cases?

- If length is zero and sum is zero then the empty sequence is the only solution.
- If length is zero and sum is non-zero then there is no solution.

We can easily implement these rules:

```
  if (length == 0)
  {
    if (sum == 0)
      yield return Enumerable.Empty<int>();
    yield break;
  }
```

All right, that deals with length being zero. What about length non-zero? Are there any base cases there?  Yes. If `least * length` is greater than `sum` then there cannot be any solution.

```
  if (least * length > sum)
    yield break;
```

All right. We know that length is at least 1 and that there is definitely a solution.  What are the solutions? Well, there has to be a first number in the sequence, and it can be any value between least and sum, so let's write a loop.

```
  for (int current = least; current <= sum; current += 1)
  {
```

What is the solution given `current`?  It is `current` followed by a sequence of size `length-1` where the smallest item is `current` or larger that sums to `sum - current`. But we can compute that recursively!

```
    var head = Enumerable.Repeat(current, 1);
    foreach(var tail in SumsTo(sum - current, current, length - 1))
      yield return head.Concat(tail);
  }
}
```

And we're done:

```
    Console.WriteLine(SumsTo(28, 0, 12).Count());
```

Prints out 3036, as expected and takes a fraction of a second; there are 3036 ways to sum 12 numbers from 0 to 28 to 28.

---

**EXERCISE**: make a type `Sum` that is either (1) empty, or (2) an integer, called the head, followed by a `Sum` (either empty or made of only larger elements) called the tail.  Rewrite the solution so that it returns `IEnumerable<Sum>` rather than `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>>`.

**EXERCISE**: Make your `Sum` type implement `IEnumerable<int>` correctly.

**EXERCISE**: We generate some sums over and over again; for example, of the 3036 solutions to the length is 12, sum is 28 problem, over 100 of them end with "5, 5" so we're allocating that object many times. Memoize your solution so that it returns the same `Sum` object when given the same arguments.

**EXERCISE**: Compute the approximate amount of computation you *save* with this memoized solution; contrast that with the amount of memory you use. Did memory usage go up or down? Did computation speed go up or down? What does this tell you about the efficiency of memoization for this problem? Can you propose a better memoization algorithm?

**EXERCISE**: I have a particular pattern for strings in mind; we'll call them frob strings. It goes like this:  `()` is a frob string, and `(XY)` where `X` and `Y` are replaced with frob strings is a frob string.  So for example `(()())` is a frob string, as is `(()(()()))`.  Make a method `static IEnumerable<string> AllFrob(int s)` that gives all frob strings with `s` pairs of parentheses.  So `AllFrob(1)` is just `()`.  `AllFrob(2)` is empty; there are no frob strings with two pairs of parentheses. `AllFrob(3)` is `(()())`, `AllFrob(4)` is empty, `AllFrob(5)` is `(()(()()))` and `((()())())`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking time to help me. I will make sure I will do the exercises when I get a chance. What I actually wants was all possible numbers that  chosen.Sum() + chosen.Length == 28.   like 0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,3,3  OR 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,14 OR 0,0,2,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2. I think your solution give me some idea. I will up vote your answer once I review it tonight again.

Comment: @Zola: Thanks for clarifying. Note that solving the problem for all sums such that `sum + length = total` is just a simple extension of solving the problem "sums of given length equal to given total". That is, if you can solve the latter problem, then it is straightforward to adapt that solution to solve your problem. So concentrate on the simpler problem.